# virtual real time limit (178/120s) reached

Tags: python, ubuntu, odoo

I am using ubuntu 16 version and running Odoo erp system 12.0 version.
On my application log file i see information says "virtual real time limit (178/120s) reached".
What exactly it means & what damage it can cause to my application?
Also how i can increase the virtual real time limit?

Comment: Do you mean the Odoo log file? Can you please put this logline into your question?

Comment: I assume this is what you are looking for?https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/28808 are you running in debug mode?

Answer (score 16):

It's a parameter to add resilience to the Odoo server by killing zombie threads and spawning new ones. It won't harm your application but it limits your time for debugging if you don't change it.

According to Odoo's own documentation (see https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/cmdline.html)

> --limit-time-real  Prevents the worker from taking longer than  seconds to process a request. If the limit is exceeded, the
>   worker is killed.
>
> Differs from --limit-time-cpu in that this is a “wall time” limit
>   including e.g. SQL queries.
>
> Defaults to 120.

So, to be able to debug in peace, I run Odoo with --limit-time-real 99999