# Reloading error while sending email in survey to list of emails in odoo12

Tags: email, odoo, odoo-12, reloading

I created new database in odoo12 and install survey module. And when i try to share survey to multiple user(more than 50) by putting list of email ids in 'list of email' field. It send survey email to some users but after that it stop by throwing 'reloading error'. So, anybody can help for this odoo issue.

Error message on terminal is below:

```
2020-09-01 09:48:00,618 2920 WARNING ? odoo.service.server: Thread <Thread(odoo.service.http.request.140297178703616, started 140297178703616)> virtual real time limit (136/120s) reached. 
2020-09-01 09:48:00,618 2920 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Dumping stacktrace of limit exceeding threads before reloading 
2020-09-01 09:48:00,785 2920 INFO ? odoo.tools.misc: 
# Thread: <Thread(odoo.service.http.request.140297178703616, started 140297178703616)> (db:new_db) (uid:2) (url:http://localhost:8012/web/dataset/call_button)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884, in _bootstrap
  self._bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
  self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
  self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
  self.handle()
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 228, in handle
  rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 418, in handle
  self.handle_one_request()
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 263, in handle_one_request
  return self.run_wsgi()
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 205, in run_wsgi
  execute(self.server.app)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in execute
  application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 434, in app
  return self.app(e, s)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
  return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
  result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1320, in __call__
  return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1293, in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 599, in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1488, in dispatch
  result = ir_http._dispatch()
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/website_sale/models/ir_http.py", line 15, in _dispatch
  return super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/auth_signup/models/ir_http.py", line 19, in _dispatch
  return super(Http, cls)._dispatch()
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_http.py", line 22, in _dispatch
  return super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/http_routing/models/ir_http.py", line 403, in _dispatch
  result = super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/utm/models/ir_http.py", line 26, in _dispatch
  response = super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 208, in _dispatch
  result = request.dispatch()
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
  result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
  return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 98, in wrapper
  return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
  result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 941, in __call__
  return self.method(*args, **kw)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
  response = f(*args, **kw)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 966, in call_button
  action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
  return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 759, in call_kw
  return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
  result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo-custom-addons/surveymanagement/survey_management/wizard/survey_email_compose_message.py", line 113, in send_mail_action
  return self.send_mail()
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo-custom-addons/surveymanagement/survey_management/wizard/survey_email_compose_message.py", line 324, in send_mail
  create_response_and_send_mail(wizard, token, partner.id, email)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo-custom-addons/surveymanagement/survey_management/wizard/survey_email_compose_message.py", line 220, in create_response_and_send_mail
  Mail.create(values).send()
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_mail.py", line 265, in send
  smtp_session=smtp_session)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_mail.py", line 370, in _send
  msg, mail_server_id=mail.mail_server_id.id, smtp_session=smtp_session)
File: "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_mail_server.py", line 501, in send_email
  smtp.sendmail(smtp_from, smtp_to_list, message.as_string())
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 882, in sendmail
  (code, resp) = self.data(msg)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 569, in data
  (code, msg) = self.getreply()
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 387, in getreply
  line = self.file.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
  return self._sock.recv_into(b)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1012, in recv_into
  return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 874, in read
  return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 631, in read
  v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer) 
2020-09-01 09:48:00,786 2920 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Initiating server reload
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [virtual real time limit (178/120s) reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510726/virtual-real-time-limit-178-120s-reached)

Comment: According to the first line of log (The `WARNING`), you got a ``virtual real time limit (136/120s) reached`` warning.

Comment: Does this email content's Images or PDF?

Comment: nothing @BhaveshOdedra